# Pandas pivot_table custom aggfunc

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

How does pivot table evaluate the function I created?

Does it pass all the values at once and only return the values between the .25 and .75 quantile? Or does it evaluate each value at a time and determine if it fits between the .25 and .75 quantile?

```
def Mean_Outliers_Removed(values):
   mid_quantiles = values.quantile([.25, .75])
   return np.mean(mid_quantiles)


pivotall= pd.pivot_table(dftat,index=['Service','Month','1 Type','2 Type' ], 
           values=['1 TAT mins', '2 TAT mins'],aggfunc=[np.mean,Mean_Outliers_Removed,
                                                       np.std,len],margins=True)
```

Thanks in advance.

```
edit
1 TAT mins  1 Type  2 Type  2 TAT mins  Service Month
31479.6 OP  NAP 31405.8 RAD Jun-18
18561   OP  RAD 18576   RAD Jun-18
18507   OP  RAD 18727.8 RAD Jun-18
18429   OP  SP  18427.8 RAD Jun-18
18315   INP SP  18408   RAD Jun-18
17835.6 OP  SP  17835   RAD Jun-18
17736   OP  SP  17734.8 RAD Jun-18
17517   OP  RAD 17611.8 RAD Jun-18
17115.6 INP US  17815.8 CARD    Jun-18
13149.6 OP  RAD 13279.8 RAD Jun-18
13146   OP  SP  13144.8 RAD Jun-18
11500.8 OP  RAD 11500.8 RAD Jun-18
11116.8 OP  RAD 11293.8 RAD Jun-18
10966.8 OP  SP  10966.8 RAD Jun-18
10419.6 OP  NAL 10419   RAD Jun-18
10288.8 OP  XT  10287.6 RAD Jun-18
10252.8 OP  XT  10251.6 RAD Jun-18
10018.8 OP  RAN 10018.8 RAD Jun-18
9849    OP  RAN 9847.8  RAD Jun-18
9687    OP  RAN 9727.8  RAD Jun-18
8538.6  INP SP  10282.8 CARD    Jun-18
8199.6  OP  SP  8199    RAD Jun-18
```

Comment: what do you mean by sample data, are those the values of dftat?

Comment: yes, that is the sample data from the column being evaluated in dftat.

Comment: You should provide data that can actually be used in your above code. Your use of `pd.pivot_table` is calling several columns, yet you've only provided 1.

Comment: it would be helpful if you print a sample of dftat

Comment: thank you for the suggestions, I added some more sample data